# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (PhoneNumber, City, Email, KYCDocument, Image, Speciality) specified for Doctor

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a form using modelsform, it was working fine but, suddenly I don't know what suddenly happens and it started giving me this error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (PhoneNumber, City, Email, KYCDocument, Image, Speciality) specified for Doctor` I have checked this error online and tried some solutions but nothing workout form me .

here is forms.py file

```
from django import forms

from .models import Doctor


class Doctorslist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name','PhoneNumber','Email','City','Speciality','Image','KYCDocument')
```

here is models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# Create your models here.
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    speciality =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    doc_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blog_images', verbose_name = "Image")
    kycdocument = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blog_images', verbose_name = "kycImage")
```

Comment: The names in `Doctorslist.Meta.fields` don't match the field names on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields should take the name of the fields in your model, so:

```
class Doctorslist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'city', 'speciality', 'doc_image', 'kycocument')
```

You thus should *not* use the `verbose_name` of a field, or capitalize the fields. These are simply the names of the fields you define in the form.

If you want to show these fields in a different way at the HTML side, you can define a [**`verbose_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) for that field, or set a `label` in the form. For example:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Doctor's name", max_length=20)
    # …
```

or in the form with the [**`labels`** option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
class Doctorslist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'city', 'speciality', 'doc_image', 'kycocument')
        labels = {
            'name': "doctor's name"
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so  much, I forgot to make field name same